# How can I print a Perl hash in specific order?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @a = ("b","a","d","c");
my %h = ("a",1,"b",2,"c",3,"d",4);

#print '"' . join('","', @a), "\"\n";

print "\n";
foreach my $key (@a) {
    print '"' . $h{$key} . '",';
}
print "\n";
```

that outputs

```
"2","1","4","3",
```

but I would like that it just outputted

```
"2","1","4","3"
```

Notice that last ',' isn't there.

Is it possible to e.g. print a hash in a specific order, or some other trick to get the output I want?

Update:

Based on friedo's answer I was able to get it right.

```
print '"' . join('","', @h{@a}), "\"\n";
```

Friedo's answer doesn't have the quotes around the values.

Comment: `"\"\n"` is better written as `qq{"\n}`

Comment: A `map` based solution like `gbacon`'s will work in cases where `@a` has zero elements.  Your solution will print: `""\n`, which is equivalent to having one element in `@a` whose value is an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) to get the values, then use `join` to stick them together with commas.

```
print join ",", @h{@a};
```

Comment: This doesn't include the requested double quotes.

Answer (score 10):

```
print join("," => map qq["$_"], @h{@a}), "\n";
```

At the heart of this line is `@h{@a}`, a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) that means the same as

```
($h{"b"}, $h{"a"}, $h{"d"}, $h{"c"})
```

The obvious advantage is economy of expression.

Moving out one level, we find the [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) operator: for each value from `@h{@a}`, wrap it in double quotes using `qq["$_"]`. Because you want double quotes in the result, the code uses [`qq//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) to switch delimiters. Otherwise, you'd be stuck with `"\"$_\""` or a concatenation chain as in your question.

Finally, [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) inserts commas between the mapped values. In this case, [`=>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) is identical to the comma operator, but I use it here instead of

```
join(",", ...)
```

which I find visually unpleasing because of the commas being crammed together.

You may be tempted to write the `join` without parentheses, but doing so would make `"\n"` an argument to `join` rather than `print`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `join` to put commas between values and not at the end, and `map` to wrap each value in double quotes.

```
print join(",", map { qq|"$h{$_}"| } @a);
```